# Switch inside a function doesn't work correctly in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to use Typescript with Redux, and design them according to Redux Ducks. I am struggling with this typecheck here and I cannot figure out why.

```js
const UPDATE = "ticTacToe/board/update";
const RESET = "ticTacToe/board/reset";

export default function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: IBoardActions
): IBoardState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE:
      const { nextPlayer, clickedIndex } = action;
            // TypeScript error: Property 'nextPlayer' does not exist on type 
           //'{ type: string; nextPlayer: string; clickedIndex: number; } | { type: string; }'.  TS2339
      const newSquares = [...state.squares];
      newSquares[clickedIndex] = nextPlayer;
      return {
        squares: newSquares,
        oIsNext: !state.oIsNext
      };
    case RESET:
      return initialState
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

type BoardAction = typeof updateBoard | typeof resetBoard;

export type IBoardActions = ReturnType<BoardAction>;

export function updateBoard(nextPlayer: string, clickedIndex: number) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE,
    nextPlayer,
    clickedIndex
  };
}

export function resetBoard() {
  return {
    type: RESET
  };
}
```

I have tried to fix it with `enum`, but this doesn't work as well. Is that the problem of `switch`?

```
enum Action {
  UPDATE = 'update',
  RESET = 'reset'
}

export default function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: IBoardActions
): IBoardState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Action.UPDATE:
      const { nextPlayer, clickedIndex } = action;
      //TypeScript error: Property 'nextPlayer' does not exist on type '{ type: Ac
tion; nextPlayer: TicTacToeSymbols; clickedIndex: number; } | { type: Acti
on; }'.  TS2339
      const newSquares = [...state.squares];
      newSquares[clickedIndex] = nextPlayer;
      return {
        squares: newSquares,
        oIsNext: !state.oIsNext
      };
    case Action.RESET:
      return initialState
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

type BoardAction = typeof updateBoard | typeof resetBoard;

export type IBoardActions = ReturnType<BoardAction>;

export function updateBoard(nextPlayer: TicTacToeSymbols, clickedIndex: number) {
  return {
    type: Action.UPDATE,
    nextPlayer,
    clickedIndex
  };
}

export function resetBoard() {
  return {
    type: Action.RESET
  };
}
```

Why am I getting this error? It seems like my typing is correct based on the error message.

Comment: looks like you need to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). Note that discriminated unions require a literal string type instead of the general `string` type. Right now, `IBoardActions` is of type `{ type: string; nextPlayer: string; clickedIndex: number; } | { type: string; }`. Notice that the type of the `type` property is `string`. **Not** a string literal.

Comment: Based on the typing, the action can be either `updateBoard` or `resetBoard` (see `|` operator). Next player does not exist in `resetBoard` action. Hence TS is complaining about the same. Add optional chaining `?.` or add `nextPlayer`  in `resetAction`

Comment: @Vishnu Optional chaining will not work in this case. Optional chaining is for accessing nullable properties, not possibly non existent properties. The union type must be narrowed first.

Comment: OP, please try and make a minimal reproducible example on typescript playground. Include the definitions for `UPDATE` and `RESET`. Specifically, their types must be constant string literals for discriminated unions to work.

Comment: @Chase yeah my bad. An `if` condition should be fine.

Comment: @Chase I have added those definition back. I have just tried to do this with `enum`, but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). Note that the type of `IBoardActions` in your snippet is-

```
{ type: string; nextPlayer: string; clickedIndex: number; } | { type: string; }
```

But in reality, you want-

```
{ type: typeof UPDATE; nextPlayer: string; clickedIndex: number; } | { type: typeof RESET; }
```

This speaks explicitly that the first alternative is only used when the `type` property has the same type as that of `UPDATE`, and similarly for `RESET`.

But in your case, both `UPDATE` and `RESET` are of type `string`. There's no way to discriminate them.

This is where string literal types come in, change your definition of `UPDATE` and `RESET` to-

```
const UPDATE = "ticTacToe/board/update" as const;
const RESET = "ticTacToe/board/reset" as const;
```

The `as const` syntax is known as [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). If you notice, the type of `UPDATE` has now become a string literal set to its value, same for `RESET`.

Here's a [playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqgBQCIEEAqBRGBeGAiKAS2DQEMSQBTAegCMRSAnAE2oFcAHZ0qSvGUhBihIUANwBYAFAjoMAEoYAyhjQ58REuTRU6DFtUaUIlKP0HDw0SVOmUAHhxCNYzSgDNSbADax3bMGAicBgjZjZgSkYACmkYASDCcAAuGABJACF9ZhREq2kAShgAbziYCAB3QihgAAsYaPJgsAA6KABPDkoi0ql4+OBBSnhkdAxksv6E5pawBygEb1J2qJsp+OpqGAA9GAA5JkYQCqFQRiMg73bJ-tojUgBrNf7BkwVlVQm+9aaksGepndKI9ngBfaTg2xSDpdGBZJg5PJgdQwyggdwwTjcXjwlgwAA+MFR6NCxlMuOYNjsjmcsFR6QpuWaQlw8lMbEYYDQnUoAB5GUiAHxUqQOJwuGD+QLNTFcHiUCnROb2BZLFaMVLQRiEMAAcwANMJvMQHpRmGkwG57KkwGwALa0KI9MpGKAc5G9Kao1KIVCYfU3ZWq5ZRAPfAbG4Cm82WhxlUE2SHU8V+AJI0kmKCK53fV3uko3b3vFRoeOJ6RAA)

Comment: Thank you @Chase I think this is the solution I need. But I don't understand why `enum` doesn't work for this as well, do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @JohnWinston enums keys are not the right usecase for discriminated unions. All enum keys have the same type - the type of the enum itself. There's no discrimination between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use interface like this.

```
export interface IBoardActions extends ReturnType<typeof updateBoard>, ReturnType<typeof resetBoard>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't really encourage the use of discriminated unions any more as [they have their own set of problems](https://phryneas.de/redux-typescript-no-discriminating-union) and require writing a lot of extra code.

The official recommendation is to use the official redux toolkit which has TypeScript support in mind and will reduce your code drastically. Please see the [official redux tutorial on modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) for a short introduction and then take a look at the [essentials tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#creating-the-redux-store) for more in-depth information.